# Big Oh Analysis simplification

Tags: big-o

I am trying to get a better understanding of big oh algorithm analysis.
Is there a way to simplify

> 5n⋅(log(n))³.

I am thinking it simplifies to:

> n⋅(log(n))³

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. The basic idea here is to remove constant terms where they have no effect of the rate of growth.

In this case, you have:

```
(5) x (n) x (log(n)^3)
```

and, since the `5` would simply change `1,2,3,4,5` into `5,10,15,20,25`, it has no effect on the growth *rate.*

So it can be removed.

Comment: Thanks! So is it safe to assume that n*log(n)^3 growth rate is less than n^2 growth rate?

Comment: @user3339242: over the long run, `n^2` is bigger, because `log(n)^3` is less than `n`.